# Is Visual Source Safe part of VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is Visual Source Safe part of VS 2010? I am unable to find Visual Source Safe so I was thinking of downloading VS2010 if it was a part of it.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392/best-way-to-migrate-from-vss-to-subversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a lot of research and concluded that
Visual Source is genuinely available from two sources only:

1) MSDN Subscription
2) CD from Microsoft - Buy a MS Visual Sourcesafe CD from Microsoft retail.

There ia no other way to get a genuine copy of MS Sourcesafe I am afraid!

Answer (score 0):

SourceSafe has been discontinued. The last version was released in 2005.

If you have access to a MSDN Subscription you can download Visual SourceSafe 2005!